# Generate a JWT with Apex to call a web service from another system

Tags: apex, jwt

I develop an Apex class wich calls an web service from another system.

I need to use a JWT to make the authentication but I never used it, so I don't know how to do it.

I read the Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=0) but I am not sure to understand what I esactly have to do.

Do you have an article which deals about it?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Just set the header with JWT when calling the web API. Here's some sample code that uses JWT in a http request.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
req.setEndpoint('https://reqres.in/api/users'); 
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req); 
Map<String, Object> response;

if (res.getStatusCode() == 200 ) { 
  response = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody()); 
  System.debug('response: ' + response);
}
else {
  System.debug('Error');
}
```